# equivalent condition for matrix diagonalization

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Give a $n\times n$ matrix $H$. Suppose there exist a matrix $n\times n$ $A$ such that $A^{T}HA = D$ where $D$ is some diagonal matrix. Can we conclude:

1) $H$ is diagonalizable, i.e. there exists $B$ such that $B^{-1}HB = U$, where $U$ is diagonal
2) $A = B$ and $D = U$ (up to some row re-ordering as necessary)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you take A = $O_n$ then, you get contradiction.

Comment: No, take $A$ to be the zero matrix, and $H=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is not diagonalizable